# Возврат ответа при таймауте курла

Tags: php, curl

Отправляю аяксом запрос курлом и задал таймаут 10 сек. Есть ли какой то параметр который возвращает какой то ответ при таймауте? Так как я не могу этот таймаут отловить,запрос возвращает пустой ответ.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT - Число в секундах ждать перед подключением. 0 для без конечного подключения.

CURLOPT_TIMEOUT -  Сколько времени cURL будет бежать в секундах

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400); //timeout in seconds
```

Решения для ловли тайм-оут

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['foo'])) {
        // Client
        $ch = curl_init('http://localhost/test/test_timeout.php?foo=bar');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 200);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
        $curl_error = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        if ($curl_errno > 0) {
                echo "cURL Error ($curl_errno): $curl_error\n";
        } else {
                echo "Data received: $data\n";
        }
} else {
        // Server
        sleep(10);
        echo "Done.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Ваш вариант помог спасибо!

Comment: спасибо, можете поставить галочку, чтоб другим тоже помогло?

Comment: Я отметил его сразу как верный ответ.

Comment: галочки не видно, можете еще раз сделать